# regex - match exactly 10 digits with atleast one symbol or spaces between them

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I'm trying to write a query in oracle sql to get rows which has invalid 10 digit numbers, ie with other symbols in between them.

For example:

```
(111) 111-1111       #10 digit number with some symbols and spaces in between
111-111-1111         
(111)111-1111
111)111-1111
(111) 11    1-1111
```

ie, It should match exactly 10 digit numbers which are non consecutive because it has some symbols in it.

So it should not match the following example:

```
111          #consecutive 3 digit number
11   1       #3 digit number with spaces
11-1         #3 digit number with symbol in between
1111111111   #consective 10 digit number
```

And I'm using REGEXP_LIKE, something like this

```
select * from table where REGEXP_LIKE(column, ?)
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (REGEXP_LIKE is product specific.)

Comment: I'm using oracle sql

Comment: I added the `oracle` tag. Quite essential to draw the attention of experts in that field to your question.

Comment: Remove the non digit and test the length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a combination of a regex and `length`; the latter to exclude a pure 10-digit number without other characters:

```
regexp_like(col, '^[ .()-]*(\d[ .()-]*){10}$') and length(col) > 10
```

In the `[.()-]` class you would list all the characters that you would allow as symbols among the digits. Note that `-` needs to be the last in that list or else be escaped.

If you would allow *any* non-digit to occur among the 10 digits, you can use `\D`:

```
regexp_like(col, '^\D*(\d\D*){10}$') and length(col) > 10
```

Answer (score 1):

So: the string should have length greater than 10, and the total number of digits must be exactly 10. This can be done without regular expressions (which should make it faster):

```
... where length(str) > 10 and
          length(str) = 10 + length(translate(str, 'z0123456789', 'z'))
```

`translate` will translate the letter `z` to itself and all the other characters (digits) to nothing. Having to include the `z` is annoying, but unavoidable; `translate` will return NULL if any of its arguments is NULL. The second condition says the length of the input `str` is exactly 10 more than the length of the string with all digits removed - so there are exactly 10 digits.